# I am getting "command extension:serve not found" in the Shopify app theme extension

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

[image]

[image]

I am getting this error when running `npm run dev` command - if anybody knows a solution I would appreciate the help.

This is a Shopify app template (react + nodejs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is the solution that works for me.

I uninstalled Ruby's latest version (Ruby+Devkit 3.2.0-1 (x64)) and installed the recommended version of Ruby (Ruby+Devkit 3.1.3-1 (x64)).